# Custom configuration in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I need to define such configuration parameters as the contacts of the company (phone, address etc) for using in twig templates. How am I supposed to make it? The most obvious way to me is adding them into the `app/config/config.yml` file like this:

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: en
    contacts:
        phone: 08455555050
```

Is that ok or there is any better way?

Also, the docs say I should use constants in entities for params that never change, but I don't need an entity for which would hold these data, how to be with this? I'm just starting with Symfony and confused.

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/config/definition.html, and for twig specifically: https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html

Comment: Another option is to inject parameter into your controller (or fetch it in controller - depending on your setup) then pass it to twig template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I've made it this way:

`app/config/services.yml`:

```
parameters:
    locale: en
    contacts:
        phone: '123455678'
...
twig:
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    globals:
        contacts: '%contacts%'
```

Twig:

```
<span>{{ contacts.phone }}</span>
```

Comment: A color hexadecimal is a constant.

A phone number isn't, in any case.

You need to put this parameter in the parameters.yml (don't forget about the parameters.yml.dist).

Comment: @Sergey Same as this: http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/m8rt/how-to-access-parameters-in-twig-files If you're learning symfony, I suggest you go check that blog. Symfony's documentation can be very superficial for the beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Make a [Service](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) that return your Company

A Simple getCompany that return the doctrine entity

Register the service

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:

    AppBundle\Service\MyTwigExtension:
        class: YourService
```

Register the service in [Twig global](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/global_variables.html)

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    # ...
    globals:
        # the value is the service's id
        user_management: '@AppBundle\Service\MyTwigExtension'
```

And on your base twig template you can call the service like this

`{% set Company = company.getCompanyInfo() %}`

And anywhere you need Company details you can do `Company.getMyField`

I suggest you to make a entity so the user could get a backend to modify his company details, this will be more flexible is the future

Comment: Good idea, but far too complicated for the stage I am now at, I don't need any entities at all at this point. Seems like the only way I what I described in the original question.